# What is the difference between os.system("timeout 1") and time.sleep(1)? Python

Tags: python, memory, time, operating-system, cpu

What is the difference between `os.system("timeout 1")` and `time.sleep(1)` in Python? I know the first one will call out the command line and let it do the timeout, but not sure how the second one make the system idle.

Also, which one can save more CPU power or make less memory occupied?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efficient way is using `time.sleep`.

Second method is just sleeping (idle) the process for it's own for 1 second. It doesn't use any other resources more that itself.

First method is **making an another process**, which takes more memory space, CPU, etc., and waiting to end (`os.system`'s behavior). Luckily the another process was just `timeout`, so the result seems same.